# load data into tableWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, sqlite, pyqt5

i want to load data into table Widget , this is Ui interface. when i run this code the result is crush , this ui incould function load_data to load data from database file , the name of database fie is abood.db

```
  def load_data(self):
   con = sqlite3.connect('abood.db')
   query = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
   result = con.execute(query)
   self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
   for row_number , row_data in enumerate(result):
      self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
      for cloum_number , data in enumerate(row_data):
         self.tableWidget.SetItem(row_number, cloum_number, 
         QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

How can i solve ? is there error on function load_data

Thanks

Comment: abood.db is in the same folder as your .py? you could share the .db

Comment: yes it is in same folder ( abood.db , interface.py) i will upload the file

Comment: the same, it asks me to register, upload it to dropbox or drive and share the link.

Comment: typo: change `SetItem` to `setItem`

Comment: it is working fine thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about using [QSqlTableModel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qsqltablemodel.html) with a [QTableView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtableview.html) ?